# Where Is the Registry Key for Office 2010 PIA (How to Determine If Office 2010 PIA Is Installed)

Tags: registry, key, office-2010, pia

Where is the Registry key for Office 2010 PIA?

For 2003/2007, I googled, and found:
Office 2003 PIA:

```
RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'Software\Classes\Installer\Features\9040941900063D11C8EF10054038389C')
```

Office 2007 PIA:

```
RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'Software\Classes\Installer\Features\00002105501100000000000000F01FEC')
```

Thanks.

Comment: I just searched the Registry Table, and I found this key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Features\00004109501100000000000000F01FEC.  I'm not sure if it's true.  I just cannot find any official document from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested, and the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Features\00004109501100000000000000F01FEC` makes sense.